# I need to write a C program that calls a given function to count the number of characters and digits in a file

Tags: c, arrays, count, character

I need to write a C program that counts the number of characters and digits in a file. I believe my best attempt is close, but the program must call a given function, `mostfrequent()`, and I cannot figure out how to implement it into my `main` so that they work together. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
// this is the function my program is required to use.

int mostfrequent(int *a, int length) {
    int index = 0;
    int max = a[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

// this is my closest attempt at a working program so far, but it does
// not call mostfrequent() which I need it to do.

int main() {    
    typedef FILE *ptr_file;
    int x, i, j;
    int length;
    char c;
    char ch[1000];
    int a = 65;
    c = getc(ptr_file);

    ptr_file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    while (c != EOF) {
        scanf(ptr_file, "%s", ch[i]);
        i++;

        fclose(ptr_file);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (a < 116) {
                if (char(a) == 'ch[j]')
                    char max_char_temp=(char)a
                count_temp++;
            }
            if (count_temp > count) {
                count = count_temp;
                max_char = max_char_temp;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Why use such an erratic indentation style?

Comment: I'm still a beginner and have been focusing mostly on logic. Thank you for understanding if it is difficult to follow.

Comment: First indent your code correctly, then you can **see** if the logic is correctly implemented.  For exampe, there is a missing `;` after `(char)a` and your second `main` function terminates in the middle of a block.  Look at how I have re-indented you post, and fix it.  There are plenty of problems, but the `main` function is not even closed.

Comment: regarding these two line: `int a = 65;
    c = getc(ptr_file);`    the call to `getc()` is trying to read from an uninitialized file pointer.   A excellent way to cause a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding the code block that begins with: `while (c != EOF) {`  inside that code block the file is being closed by calling `fclose()`  What ever for?  don't call fclose() until the file is completely read.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf(ptr_file, "%s", ch[i]);`  Please read the man page for `scanf()`   then you will see the parameter list is wrong and `scanf()` only inputs from `stdin`.   to input from a file, use: `fscanf()` (again, please read the man page for `fscanf()`)

Comment: for readability by us humans and for ease of documentation by tools such as `doxygen`, follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement

Comment: regarding this line: `if (a < 116) {`.  What is that 'magic' number `116`?  Strongly suggest using #define's to give  'magic' numbers meaningful names the use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: the posted code does not even come close to compiling.  When compiling always enable all the warnings, then fix all the problems enumerated by the compiler.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: regarding this expression: `'ch[j]'`.  That expression is meaningless and will not compile.  perhaps you meant: `'j'`.   regarding this expression: `char(a)`, a 'int' is (on a 32 bit architecture) 4 bytes, a 'char' is one byte so, at best, the code will look at the first byte which may be a capital 'A' or it may be 0x00, depending on the big Endian or little Endian of the underyling architecture.  Note: in most cases, a char definition (for instance 'A') will be treated as its ascii int value when comparing because in C, there is automatic 'promotion' of values for most scenarios

Comment: why is the code invoking `return` in the first iteration of a `for()` loop?

Comment: regarding this line: `typedef FILE *ptr_file;`   the `FILE` is already a typedef, defined in stdio.h, for a file descriptor structure.  So the line is nonsense.  Suggest: `FILE *ptr_file = NULL;    Where the actual pointer value will be filled in by this line: `ptr_file = fopen("file.txt", "r");`

Comment: Strongly suggest first thing to do is write a series of steps (like pseudo code) of exactly what the program is to perform.  Then look at LOTS of other code samples (stackoverflow.com has thousands of examples) to note how to implement the details of your code.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. This was my second attempt at using stack as a resource and I appreciate and will use your advice moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

regarding the question: when to call the `most_frequent()` function.

After you have created an array (which would be 36 entries long of integers),  initialize that array to all zeros, then incremented the appropriate entry for each character read from the input file. (note 36 entries allows for `a...z` + `0...9` so all other characters read from the file should be discarded.
Then pass the array and 36 to the most_frequent() function

then code similar to the following could do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctypes.h> // isalpha(), isdigit(), toupper() 

#define NUM_ALPHA (26)

int main( void )
{
    int array[36] = {'\0'};

    //...open file, etc

    //then assure all processed characters are upper case or numeric 
    // and update the count in the array 
    int ch; 
    while( ch = getc( file ) != EOF && '\n' != ch) 
    { 
        if ( isalpha(ch) ) 
        { 
            ch = toupper(ch); 
            array[ch - 'A']++;
        } 

        else if (isdigit(ch) ) 
        {
            array[ (ch-'0') + NUM_ALPHA ]++; 
        } 
    } 

    int index = mostfrequent( array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    //... do what is needed with 'index' for instance
    printf( "the highest occurring char is:" );
    if( index < NUM_ALPHA )
    {
        printf( "%c\n", index+'A' );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d\n", (index-NUM_ALPHA)+'0');
    }

    fclose( file );
    return 0;
}
```

however, note that mostfrequent() only returns the index to the first entry encountered with the max value, when there are multiple entries with the same max value.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to spend some time with this and will get back to you.